# Insert blank row after the date that has Sunday as the day google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a column in google sheets that has a range of dates.
I want to insert one blank row after dates that happen to be Sundays (I only care about the day).

The pseudo-code that I was thinking of is the following:

1. Loop through the dates column
2. Format the date so that we only grab the day in full abbreviation (i.e., Sunday)
3. If the formatted date is equal to the string "Sunday" then insert a row below that date.

Here is my current script:

```
function addRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const data = range.getValues();

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const sheetDate = data[i][0];
    const day = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "EEEE");
    if (day === "Sunday") {
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(i, 1); // I know this shouldn't be i, it should be the index of the row with the value "Sunday"
    }
  }
}
```

I think the problem is with the first argument of the `insertRowsAfter()` function. What should this argument be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that every insertion of new rows after a row position, your data range adjusts, thus, you also need to adjust the row position for the next succeeding rows that contains `Sunday`.

### Suggestion

Perhaps you can try this tweaked script below:

```
function addRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const data = range.getValues();
  var count = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = i+1; //Get the sheet row number of every data from "data" variable
    const sheetDate = data[i][0];
    const day = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "EEEE");
    if (day == "Sunday") {
      count += 1; //Count how many times "Sunday" was found
      var curRow = row+count; //Adjust the current row #
      curRow -= 1; //Subtract 1 row from the current row to match the sheet
      sheet.insertRowsAfter(curRow,1)
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Test

- Test Sheet:

> [image]

- After running the tweaked script:

> [image]

Comment: @SevenSouls I hope this helps. Just feel free to comment in case I have missed something.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works exactly as I wanted. Could you please explain the `curRow` part again? In the test example, the count for Sundays is 5. The row number is `i + 1` (because arrays are zero indexed and we need to add 1 to match the sheet). Why is `var curRow = row+count;`? How does that work in the test example? Why did you subtract 1 after? Thanks!

Comment: TBH it is quite hard for me to explain this flow further in layman's term, but I'll try my best. In your loop, every new row being inserted after a matched cell will also increase the row number of the next succeeding matched cells, so that's why I've created `var curRow = row+count;` to adjust the next succeeding row numbers by adding each of them to the previous counted instance. Without subtracting 1 row on each `curRow`, you'll get [this result](https://imgur.com/a/znHtmnS), that's why we need it to match the actual sheet rows.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! Appreciate your explanation and help!